# Rotate the direction of motion of a rect using animateMotion in SVG

Tags: animation, svg

I want the yellow rectangle to be rotated 45 degrees (which it is), but I also want the ***direction of motion*** to rotate, so that the yellow rectangle appear to go "downhill" (down the blue line). I don't want it to keep moving horizontally.

```html
<svg width="800" height="400" viewBox="0 0 800 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

 <!-- decorative circles for the ends of the blue line. -->
  <g transform="rotate(45, 400, 200)">
    <path id="myPath" d="M150,200 L650,200" fill="none"
        stroke="blue" stroke-width="5.6" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="200" r="8.94" fill="blue"  />
    <circle cx="650" cy="200" r="8.94" fill="blue"  />
  </g>

  <g>
    <rect x="0" y="0"
        fill="yellow" stroke="red" width="84" height="56"></rect>
    <animateMotion dur="4s" repeatCount="1" rotate="45"
        path="M150,200 L650,200" >
    </animateMotion>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Another way to do this is to put `<mpath xlink:href="#myPath" />` as a sub-element of the `animateMotion` SVG element. In that case you can leave out `path="M150,200 L650,200"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? I've moved the animateMotion so it only applies to the rect and added a transform to the containing `<g>` element. I could have just put the rect in the other `<g>` element I guess which would have been simpler.

```html
<svg width="800" height="400" viewBox="0 0 800 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

 <!-- decorative circles for the ends of the blue line. -->
  <g transform="rotate(45, 400, 200)">
    <path id="myPath" d="M150,200 L650,200" fill="none"
        stroke="blue" stroke-width="5.6" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="200" r="8.94" fill="blue"  />
    <circle cx="650" cy="200" r="8.94" fill="blue"  />
  </g>

  <g transform="rotate(45, 400, 200)">
    <rect x="0" y="0"
        fill="yellow" stroke="red" width="84" height="56">
        <animateMotion dur="4s" repeatCount="1"
            path="M150,200 L650,200" >
        </animateMotion>
    </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! How come your code looks nicely colored, and mine doesn't? Also why didn't I get a "Run Code Snippet" button underneath? (I prepared my question in a markdown file, and then copy-pasted the markdown into SO).

Comment: Mine is a stack snippet. I've converted yours. Click on edit to see how it's formatted.